# Can we upload applications developed by VMWARE server to App Store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, vmware-server, appstore-approval

I have developed applications using VMWare Server. Can I upload these applications to the App Store? Is there any chance to apple that it can find the application is developed in VMWare Server and apple will reject this applications?

Answer (score 1):

Who said it was against the rules to develop iPhone applications on VMWare Server?  Provided the copy of OS X you are running in your VM is legal, you have no issues (as far as I know).